# Помогите пожалуйста разобратться.. Выдача из массива

Tags: php, response

Всех приветствую,Дамы и Господа,такой момент небольшой (может и большой), не могу разобраться.
Есть файл выдачи случайного кошелька из текстового файла...

```
if(substr($uripath,0,strlen('orders'))=='orders' && strlen($uripath)>strlen('orders')) {
$response = str_replace("\n","",$response); 
$arrboot = explode("\n",file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/qiwi.txt'));
$boot = '<span>'.$arrboot[rand(0,count($arrboot)-1)].'</span>';     
$response = preg_replace('/на Qiwi кошелек <b>(.*?)<\/b>/', 'на Qiwi кошелек <b>'.$boot.'</b>', trim($response));
```

Но когда обновляется страница соответственно обновляется и выдача. Как привязать выдачу к сессии или к чему ХЗ. 
Всем заранее спасибо!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
<?php

session_start(); // Стартуем сессию

if(substr($uripath,0,strlen('orders'))=='orders' && strlen($uripath)>strlen('orders')) {
    $response = str_replace("\n", "", $response);
    $arrboot = explode("\n", file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/qiwi.txt'));
    $cash = $arrboot[rand(0, count($arrboot) - 1)]; // Записываем в переменную кошелёк рандомный
    $boot = '<span>' . $cash . '</span>'; // Выводим кошелёк в span
    $response = preg_replace('/на Qiwi кошелек <b>(.*?)<\/b>/', 'на Qiwi кошелек <b>' . $boot . '</b>', trim($response));
    $_SESSION['cash'] = $cash; // Записываем в сессию этот же кошелёк.
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!